# javascript (non jquery) slider

Tags: javascript, slider

Totally crazy but I need a non jquery, just pure javascript slider that can do something like http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/clickableLogoParade.htm

I would normally do this in jquery and it would be perfect, but long story I just can't, I need to do it in pure javascript... Anyone got anything, or should I wrtie  something myself?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using my own custom vertical slider.. tried to convert it to horizontal: http://jsfiddle.net/8nQLb/

It's not perfect but might be enough for you.. problem is that when using float the inner div elements are getting "wrapped" so the extra div with image is added too late - in the vertical version I had no such problem.

Feel free to mess around with it, I will try to improve it when I'll have some time.

Comment: Thnaks I'll take a look and let you know. Cheers

Comment: Like that site, think thats a great idea! I like your code too, thanks... Unfortunatley I don't that will suit, it's close, but think the client will moan at that though :-( Thanks for the code though becuase I was going to do something similar but thinking about it, it probably would've been similar - so you've possibly saved me some time. Not sure what to do now though :-(

Comment: @Shane - glad I could be of *some* help.. what you think will suit your client then?

Comment: @Shadow - I think that method is fine it just stutters a bit too much rather than a smooth scroll..

Comment: @Shane you can play with the numbers a bit, one is the interval in `window.setInterval("GlobalScroller();", 150);` and one is `SCROLL_PIXELS` variable.. smaller values in any of those should give smoother feel to the slider.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I couldn't previously use jquery becuase there was a conflict with joomla and mootools... But i ended up sorting this problem out and using a jquery tool... However I think you had a good solution, so I'll give you the brownie point. Thanks for you help.